# Set light color from python script

Tags: python, scripting, light, color

I would like to specify the color of a light that I add using a python script launched from the command line:

```
blender --python script.py
```

The script:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='AREA')
light_obj             = bpy.data.objects['Area']
light_obj.data.energy = 500
light_obj.color       = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

The light power is correctly set to `500`, but the light color remains at its default white color, instead of being red.

**Should I do something more to set the color of the light?**

Note that I am using **Blender 2.80** with **Debian 10**.

I noted a few weird thing:
The current online documentation of blender python api says [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Light.html#bpy.types.Light.color) that the `color` of a light is a *"float array of 3 items"*, but I get en error if I don't give 4 values. [This post](https://blenderartists.org/t/change-color-of-all-the-lights/556765/2) also talk about 3 values. Anyway, it proposes something similar to what I am trying to do: `l.color = [r, g, b]`.

Is it en error in the documentation? Is their a bug?

Comment: Try light_obj.data.color = (1, 0, 0)

Answer (score 5):

**Test code out in the console.**

Even if you are going to use a script from command line always (IMO) a good idea to test it out in the python console. (`D = bpy.data, C = bpy.context`)

When adding an object via operator, the new object added is the  `context.object`  Notice the name below is not "Area" as there are already other area lights in the scene.  Using `light_ob = bpy.data.objects["Area"]` will only work as expected if there are no other lights of that name in the blend file.

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='AREA')
{'FINISHED'}

>>> C.object #  the new object
bpy.data.objects['Area.002']
```

At any time can hit the autocomplete to see the available options.  The light is the data part of the light object.  *(In the UI Properties panel it is under the Data tab.)*

```
>>> light_ob = C.object
>>> light = light_ob.data
>>> light
bpy.data.lights['Area.002']
```

It's of type `AreaLight` which per documentation link posted in question is a subclass which inherits properties of `bpy.types.Light`

```
>> type(light)
<class 'bpy.types.AreaLight'>

>>> light.energy = 500
```

All objects have an rgba color property. For a lamp as commented above to set the lamp color set it on the data part.

```
>>> light.color = (1, 0, 0)
>>>
```

The script.

```
import bpy


bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='AREA')
light_ob = bpy.context.object
light = light_ob.data
light.energy = 500
light.color = (1, 0, 0)
```